# Determine if a resource exists in ResourceManager

Tags: c#, resources

Is there anyway to determine if a ResourceManager contains a named resource?  Currently I am catching the MissingManifestResourceException but I hate having to use Exceptions for non-exceptional situations. There must be some way to enumerate the name value pairs of a ResourceManager through reflection, or something?

**EDIT**:  A little more detail.  The resources are not in executing assembly, however the ResourceManager is working just fine.  If I try `_resourceMan.GetResourceSet(_defaultCuture, false, true)` I get null, whereas if I try `_resourceMan.GetString("StringExists")` I get a string back.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use the ResourceSet to do that, only it loads all the data into memory if you enumerate it. Here y'go:

```
    // At startup.
    ResourceManager mgr = Resources.ResourceManager;
    List<string> keys = new List<string>();

    ResourceSet set = mgr.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true);
    foreach (DictionaryEntry o in set)
    {
        keys.Add((string)o.Key);
    }
    mgr.ReleaseAllResources();

    Console.WriteLine(Resources.A);
```

Comment: When I try to get the ResourceSet from the ResourceManager I get null back.

Comment: Ok, I got it working, but I have to try to load a single resource before I can call GetResourceSet.  Wierd.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use something like [Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcenames(VS.80).aspx) to enumerate the list of resources available in the Assembly's manifest. It isn't pretty and doesn't solve all of the corner cases, but works if required.

Comment: That returns an array of zero strings.

Comment: Are the resources in a satellite resource?

Comment: You are giving him ResourceManager names, not names of resources in those ResourceManagers ;).

Comment: Interesting, I had used this to get resources along side an assembly, rather than resource managers. i.e. Project\Resources\Image.jpg -> Assembly.GetManifestresourceNames would return Project.Resources.Image.jpg. Is this not what he wanted?

Comment: Yes the resources are in a satellite resource.

Comment: In that case you'd need to use the Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames on the satellite assembly. The ResourceSet solution works as well, just can be expensive if you don't want to load everything.