# How do I copy folder(and subfolders) from my solution content into IsolatedStorage?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a folder with content in my solution, it contains lots of subdirectories. I need to copy this folder into IsolatedStorage. I read msdn forum message where it was said that there are no means to get folder content from code. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The forum ist right. There is no way to enumerate "Content" resources.

You could set build action "Resource" or "Embedded Resource" as some answers suggest - then there are ways to enumerate the resources using [ResourceManager or similar means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160022/determine-if-a-resource-exists-in-resourcemanager). But I **wouldn't recommend it** as this will embed all resources into your assembly bloating it and making your app slow to load.

Here is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456609/how-to-enumerate-images-included-as-content-in-the-xap) (about enumerating image files). No solution though. The [answer of Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456609/how-to-enumerate-images-included-as-content-in-the-xap/7474496#7474496) contains the only workaround: Prepare a list of filenames at design time and build this list into the app. Then instead of enumerating the files at runtime you read the filenames one by one from this list.

If you need this just for developing and testing then like the others I also recommend looking at the [ISETool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286408%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). You setup your app once with a reference storage and use the tool to save the state of the isolated storage. When you need to restore the state from isolated storage you can use the tool to copy the saved one back to the phone or emulator. An example for doing this can be found in [this blog post](http://blog.arsanth.com/index.php/2011/08/01/automate-wp7-isolated-storage-states-with-visual-studio/).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a lot of files as well in the subdirectories?  I see three solutions:

- Set the file build action as Resource so they are embedded in the dll. You can retrieve the folder anme in the filename of the resources (MyAssembly.MyFolder.Filename.extension).But it will slow down the loading of your assembly and so the startup time of your application.
- Set the files build action to Content so they are included in the XAP file but I'm not sure you can iterate the content without knowing the path
- You can put the content in a zipped file on a remote server, get it on the first startup and use http://slsharpziplib.codeplex.com/ to dezip the content in Isolated Storage.

Answer (score 0):

Mighter,

If I understand you right, you need the contents of your folder, along with the sub-directories in Isolated Storage, right? Putting them in your solution only gets them into the XAP.

You could use the Isolated Storage Explorer that comes bundled with the Windows Phone SDK 7.1 to manipulate file storage in Isolated Storage. This would be the easiest way to get your folder's content into Iso.

You could start learning about Isolated Storage Explorer [ISETool.exe] from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh286408%28VS.92%29.aspx).

Hope this helps!