# Is it possible to use a variable for the `[Display(Name="Something")]` data annotation in MVC3 (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, resx

not sure why, but the data annotation in MVC3 insist on having constant values, which i just can't understand for things like error messages and display names. I love these annotations, they are so easy to use and so powerful, but what if you need to support multiple languages?

Imagine i have the following model:

```
public class Person
{
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
}
```

If i dont change anything and use the CRUD views that MVC3 will build for me I get a label next to the text fields that says "First_Name", so i add the data annotation to change the display name like so:

```
public class Person
{
    [Display(Name="First name")]
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
}
```

Which works just fine. But i want to supply a different display name depending on the users language, using a function i made previously `GetDisplayName(string ToGet, string Language)` which just returns the string i am interested in, but if i change my data annotation to this:

```
public class Person
{
    [Display(Name=GetDisplayName("First_Name", "English"))]
    public string First_Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then i get a compiler error telling me that the annotation requires a constant values, WHY????

Does anyone know a way to accomplish what i am trying to do? Thanks

**UPDATE**

Ok, it appears that the best way to do this is with `.resx` resource files as per several answers below and those in other posts. which works great for the most part.

Does anyone know how i can request a resource with a variable name? not in the context of data attributes this time, but just in controllers and views.

Basically at the moment i am getting at the resources with `@Resources.SomeKey` but i would like to be able to use that within a function in a `@Resources["SomeOtherKey"]` where `SomeOtherKey` is a dynamically generated string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have your translated property names in Resource Files, that is supported out of the box... no need to extend the framework.

Just use:

```
[Display(Name = "Resource_Key", ResourceType = typeof(DataFieldLabels))]
public string myProperty { get; set; }
```

Where the "Resource_Key" is the key in your resource files... and the "DataFieldLabels" is the name of your base resource file.

**EDIT:**

In order to access resource files dynamically you can do:

```
ResourceSet resset = ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(culture, true, false);
var translated = resset.GetString("myToken")
```

Comment: Oh right, I have been using my database to store all the localised Text, i should imagine you are all going to tell me that's the wrong thing to do now..... ;-)

Comment: no but you'll beed a db resource provider: http://weblogs.asp.net/thangchung/archive/2010/06/25/extending-resource-provider-for-soring-resources-in-the-database.aspx

Comment: I have spent the day switch over to use the `.resx` XML files for storing my text, because follow your (and others) answer i have decided that is the way to go. Romias or @AdamTuliper , do you know how i can request a resource with a variable name? not in the context of data attributes this time, but just in controllers and views. Basically at the moment i am getting at the resources with `@Resources.SomeKey` but i would like to be able to use that within a function in a `@Resources["SomeOtherKey"]` where `SomeOtherKey` is a dynamically generated string. will update question too

Comment: ResourceSet resset = ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(culture, true, false);

resset.GetString("myToken")

Comment: my `ResourceManager` doesnt seem to have a `GetResourceSet()` method :-(

Comment: Its not a static method you need a resourcemanagerinstance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.getresourceset.aspx   see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160022/determine-if-a-resource-exists-in-resourcemanager

Answer (score 1):

DataAnnotations param values require constants, i.e. actual strings.

Comment: Actually, this is true about all Attributes, not just DataAnnotations, but you've got the right idea.

Comment: That's what I figured, but the question was why and is there anyway around it.

Answer (score 1):

You can only assign constants.

You can do an extension and assign keyValues there and then the extension fetches from somewhere else, like a database or a resource file or a webservice or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [Hanselman's post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx) regarding internationalization. Maybe it could help

Answer (score -1):

```
[Display(Name = "strResourceString", ResourceType = typeof(Resourcefile.strResourceString))]
```

Comment: the question was asking if *variables* can be used; not resources.