# Can I tell MVC to separate pascal-cased properties in to words automatically?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, displayname-attribute

I often have C# code like

```
    [DisplayName("Number of Questions")]
    public int NumberOfQuestions { get; set; }
```

Where I use the `DisplayName` property to  add in spaces when it is displayed. Is there an option to tell MVC to add spaces by default if the `DisplayName` annotation is not explicitly provided?

Comment: According to this answer, you can only apply constants,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11654740/is-it-possible-to-use-a-variable-for-the-displayname-something-data-anno

Comment: you could probably have your own custom `DisplayFor`, where you grabbed the property name and manipulated it.  But I'd opt for just hardcoding it.

Comment: Use reflection to get property name from class definition, then create a custom `Html.DisplayFor` or using `DisplayTemplate` containing regex which inserting whitespaces between end of previous word (if exists) and capital letters.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways.

1.Override **LabelFor** and creating a custom HTML helper:

- Utility class for Custom HTML helper:

  ```
  public class CustomHTMLHelperUtilities
  {
  // Method to Get the Property Name
  internal static string PropertyName<T, TResult>(Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression)
   {
      switch (expression.Body.NodeType)
      {
          case ExpressionType.MemberAccess:
              var memberExpression = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
              return memberExpression.Member.Name;
          default:
              return string.Empty;
      }
   }
   // Method to split the camel case
   internal static string SplitCamelCase(string camelCaseString)
   {
      string output = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(
          camelCaseString,
          "([A-Z])",
          " $1",
          RegexOptions.Compiled).Trim();
      return output;
   }
  }
  ```
- Custom Helper:

  ```
  public static class LabelHelpers
  {
   public static MvcHtmlString LabelForCamelCase<T, TResult>(this HtmlHelper<T> helper, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression, object htmlAttributes = null)
    {
      string propertyName = CustomHTMLHelperUtilities.PropertyName(expression);
      string labelValue = CustomHTMLHelperUtilities.SplitCamelCase(propertyName);

      #region Html attributes creation
      var builder = new TagBuilder("label ");
      builder.Attributes.Add("text", labelValue);
      builder.Attributes.Add("for", propertyName);
      #endregion

      #region additional html attributes
      if (htmlAttributes != null)
      {
          var attributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(htmlAttributes);
          builder.MergeAttributes(attributes);
      }
      #endregion

      MvcHtmlString retHtml = new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString(TagRenderMode.SelfClosing));
      return retHtml;

    }
  }
  ```
- Use in CSHTML:

  ```
  @Html.LabelForCamelCase(m=>m.YourPropertyName, new { style="color:red"})
  ```

  Your label will display as **'Your Property Name'**

2.Using Resource File:

```
[Display(Name = "PropertyKeyAsperResourceFile", ResourceType = typeof(ResourceFileName))]
public string myProperty { get; set; }
```

I will prefer the first solution. Because a resource file is intend to do a separate and reserved role in a project. Additionally the custom HTML helper can be reused once created.

Answer (score 0):

Humanizer is a very popular library that I've used for this.

https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer

```
"PascalCaseInputStringIsTurnedIntoSentence".Humanize() => "Pascal case input string is turned into sentence"
```